# Cannot find .cls file even when kpsewhich displays path

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, ubuntu

So I was attempting to add a `.cls` file to the local tree. So I created the a `/home/.textmf` directory and ran `sudo tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME $HOME/.texmf` on it.

The `.cls` file (`res.cls`) is placed under `/home/.textmf/tex/latex`, and using `kpsewhich res.cls` yields `/home/zhehao/texmf/tex/latex/res/res.cls`, which is the expected location.

However, when I run `pdflatex`, it still reminds me that "LaTeX Error: File `res.cls` not found."

Any help?

Comment: Your first reference to `res.cls` points to the wrong location. What about running `texhash`?

Comment: if kpsewhich and pdflatex are using different search paths they will be from different installations, check `which pdftex` and `which kpsewhich`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is `textmf` a typo? The correct name is `texmf` and comes from "tex" (program TeX) and "mf" (program Metafont), two programs created by Donald E. Knuth.

Comment: `/home/textmf` is not the same as `$HOME/.texmf`. First, `/home` is not the same directory as `$HOME`. Second, `texmf` is not the same as `textmf`. Third, `.texmf` is not the same as `texmf`. Moreover, you dhould not need to do anything to configure `TEXMFHOME` if you are using TeX Live on a Unix-like system. Presumably, you are on Linux. Then `$HOME/texmf` is default. Why do you want to change it to `$HOME/.texmf`?